# How to reduce size of an iOS app built with kivy-ios?

Tags: ios, mobile, kivy

We're building an iOS app using Kivy-iOS.
Our current app size is 397MB (as compared to 40MB for the same app deployed on Android using Buildozer).
We need to drastically reduce the size of this app but can't figure out how to do it.
Are there parts of the `kivy-ios` library that we could exclude to reduce the app size?
If so, how would we do it?
So far, we've gone one-by-one both within the tools folder of `kivy-ios` and within `xCode`s 'linked frameworks and libraries' but haven't been able to eliminate anything of substantial size while also successfully deploying the app.

Comment: You may like to ask this on the kivy-users mailing list or irc, I'm not sure if many/any of our ios using devs watch stackoverflow much.